# PHP - How to select records from last 30 days MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, select

I have a table with a column name "ordered_at" where I have entered the value of `time()`. How can I select records from the last 30 days?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`datediff`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) to get the number of days passed between `current_date` and the value in the column:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, ordered_at) <= 30
```